# Korean input works everywhere except TeXworks

Tags: keyboard-layout, ibus

I followed the instructions [here](https://davejansen.com/enable-korean-input-on-ubuntu-19-10/) to enable Hangeul (Korean) typing on my Ubuntu 20.04 installation using IBusHangul.

Everything works perfectly fine *except* in TeXworks and TeXmaker. In both programs, if I switch to the Korean keyboard layout, pressing backspace produces the character `（`, pressing the left arrow key produces `ｑ`, and pressing the right arrow key produces `ｓ`. (Notice these are fixed-width character entities instead of the usual `(`, `q`, and `s`.

I thought this issue was particular to TeXworks, but searching around, I found people reporting similar issues with [Vim](https://ufris.tistory.com/23) and [Vi](https://withcoding.com/23) (both links are in Korean, unfortunately). In the former case, the reported solution was to make the following changes to the Vim config:

```
set number                           " show line numbers
set tabstop=4                        " set tab to 4 spaces
set ignorecase                       " ignore case in text searches
set hlsearch                         " highlight text when searching
set nocompatible                     " move using arrow keys
set fileencodings=utf-8,euc-kr       " encoding to use when saving files: utf-8, euc-kr
set fencs=ucs-bom,utf-8,euc-kr       " Korean files in euc-kr, Unicode files in utf-8
set bs=indent,eol,start              " make backspace usable
set ruler                            " show location in the status bar
set title                            " show title
set showmatch                        " show matching brackets
syntax on                            " syntax highlighting
```

**Which of these settings are actually necessary for Korean input to work, and how can I achieve the same in TeXworks (and TeXmaker)?**

Is it possible to avoid using the obsolete EUC-KR encoding?

- Ubuntu version: 20.04
- TeXworks version: 0.6.6 (MiKTeX 21.6)
- TeXmaker version: 5.0.3
- IBus version: IBus 1.5.22

Perhaps the issue is with the Qt framework, which is used by both TeXworks and TeXmaker.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I am not sure, but both Qt and Unicode CKJ Font things should be set properly. https://texwiki.texjp.org/?TeXworks https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/how-to-write-japanese-with-latex In order to type or save it. Check which font is used onto your TeXWorks.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the issue does not arise when compiling TeX documents. For example, if I write a document in Gedit, then *open* it in TeXworks and press compile, there are no problems. It's just the editor itself that doesn't work. I also changed the TeXworks interface font to a CKJ KR font with no effect.

Comment: I don't use TeXworks and can't help you with that (sorry!), but since Korean works elsewhere, if no one can give you a better solution, perhaps you can try `kile` to see if that works for you?